# How to use After_save with condition for create a object in save DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I have this in my authorization model:

```
after_save :generate_charged, :if => :authorization?
```

I need that execute this method :generate_charged only if the Authorization is created by model Authorization, because in my code, I have Refinancings that too create Authorization.

In my authorization_model has:

```
def authorization?
  # If create from Authorization == true
  # My routes /authorization can serve for something?
end
```

Comment: how about some specific models code in your question?

Comment: `after_save` belongs in the model, not the controller. That said, I think it's pretty clear what you're trying to do, but more code might be helpful.  Where is `generate_changed`? What does it do?  How do refinancings create authorizations?

Comment: Ops, sorry, I meant Authorization model instead of controller, I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `after_save`, you can just put this logic in your `authorization_controller`:

```
def create
  attrs = { your form attrs }
  if @authorization.update_attributes(attrs)
    @authorization.generate_charged
    # then, redirect
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Then, of course, in your Refinancings controller, don't call that method.

There are ways to do this with after save (i.e. setting an extraneous variable to check within the model), but probably overkill for your situation. And even then, you would have code in your controller to make this happen. So bypassing all that, I think, is the shortest path.